# check if directory exists - if not, create it. vb.net

Tags: vb.net, upload, ftp

Hopefully, this is my last question regarding this project! Thanks in advance for any guidance.

I'm trying to check if a directory exists on my FTP and if not, then create the folder. This is my code...

```
strID = TextBox1.Text

If (Not System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails.Contains(strID)) Then
        Dim FTPReq As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = CType(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("ftp://username:pass@ftpaddress.ftp.net/" & strID), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
        FTPReq.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory
    End If
```

This does nothing, I get FTP error 550 file not available. I was pretty sure I had this working before but I think I might have forgot to save :(

Comment: have you seen http://howtostartprogramming.com/vb-net/vb-net-tutorial-26-ftp-upload/

Comment: Yes and have used that code just fine, but it's not about uploading a file. I can upload/download just fine using My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile() or UploadFile(). I need to see if a directory exists and if it doesn't, then create the directory. If I upload a file and the directory is not there, it throws a 550 error from the FTP.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim FTPReqResponse As System.Net.FtpWebResponse = CType(FTPReq.GetResponse(), System.Net.FtpWebResponse)
```

was all that is needed.